# When I updated Wordpress's latest version now shows this error

Tags: wordpress

Deprecated: category_link is deprecated since version 2.5.0! Use term_link instead. in /var/sentora/hostdata/tipsandtr/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5088

Answer (score 0):

Just update "Yoast SEO" plugin and problem would be solved.